# Need modification in References (using authordate1.bst)

Tags: authordate1.bst, modification

I'm trying with

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Contents of **.bib** file

```
@Article{year_2000,
  author  = {Acemoglu, Daron and Robinson, James A.},
  title   = {Why did the West Extend the Franchise? Democracy, Inequality, and Growth in Historical Perspective},
  journal = {Quarterly Journal of Economics},
  year    = {2000},
  volume  = {5},
  number  = {2},
  pages   = {1-9},
}


@Article{year_2005,
  author   = {Acemoglu, Daron and Johnson, Simon and Robinson, James},
  title    = {The Rise of Europe: Atlantic Economic Growth.},
  journal  = {American Judicial Review},
  year     = {2005},
  volume   = {9},
  number   = {1},
  pages    = {546-89},
  comment  = {This paper argues that the Atlantic trade was the key to driving European
    economic growth
    
    
    Atlantic traders: Britain, France, Spain, Portugal, Netherlands
    
    
    Interaction between medieval political institutions and trade access
    was crucial
    
    - Key was nonabsolutist political institutions (Britain, Netherlands)
    
    
    Evidence:
    
    - Urbanization rates grew faster in the Atlantic trading nations
    
    - GDP per capita estimates from Madison showing faster growth in Atlantic
    trading nations
    
    - Use either dummy for Atlantic trader or ratio of Atlantic coast
    to area as key independent variables
    
    
    Argue against other theories of "why europe" such as culture, religion,
    geography, etc.
    
    Consistent with theories emphasizing the empirtance of atlantic trade,
    colonializm and slavery profits
    
    - But profits of trade were not large enough to directly explain European
    capital accumulation
    
    - Instead, they argue that trade aided the development of political
    institutions that aided growth, such as constraints on the monarch
    
    - Channel was that commercial interests became powerful enough through
    trade to get these reforms
    
    
    But these rich traders only emerged in countries with less absolutist
    regimes
    
    
    Hypothesis seems cyclical: Countries with regimes that had less control
    led to commercial growth which generated rules that limited regime's
    control
    
    
    Provides case studies of Britain and The Netherlands to support the
    hypothesis that less absolutist regimes in these countries meant
    that merchants could grow wealthier
    
    See evidencein Acemoglu etal 2002.
    
    
    Data contribution: They create a measure of institutional quality
    from 1300-1850 based on "constraint on the executive"},
  file     = {acemoglu_johnson_.pdf:acemoglu_johnson_.pdf:PDF},
  groups   = {Institutions and Culture, European Econ History},
  keywords = {Economic Growth of Open Economies F030, Economic History: Macroeconomics; Growth and Fluctuations: Europe: Pre-2013 N139, Measurement of Economic Growth; Aggregate Productivity; Cross-Country Output Convergence G470},
}
```

Output

[image]

I need to get the output as,  all entries with two or more authors (or editors), the names of the authors (or editors) following the first one should be inverted, i.e., presented with first name (including any initials that are part of the first name) followed by the last name (accounting for any middle initials between the first and last names), as marked on the first page of the bibliography (p. 648). In the case of references with two authors (or editors), the comma following the first author (or editor) and preceding the conjunction (“&”) should be deleted. Have clearly marked below:

[image]

Kindly advise also please excuse for my poor language ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Copy the code below to a file `my_authordate1.bst` and change the `\bibliographystyle` command to

```
\bibliographystyle{my_authordate1}
```

**Contents of `my_authordate1.bst`:**

```
ENTRY
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    edition
    editor
    howpublished
    institution
    journal
    key
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    type
    volume
    year
  }
  {}
  { label extra.label sort.label }

INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }

FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=
}

STRINGS { s t u }

FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
    { add.period$ write$
      newline$
      "\newblock " write$
    }
    { output.state before.all =
        'write$
        { add.period$ " " * write$ }
      if$
    }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}

FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.year.month.check}
{ year empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
    { add.period$ write$
      month empty$
        { " " year * extra.label * "." *
          after.sentence 'output.state :=
        }
        { " " year * extra.label * " (" * month * ")." *
          after.sentence 'output.state :=
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.year.check}
{ year empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
    { add.period$ write$
      " " year * extra.label * "." *
      after.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem[" write$
  label write$
  "]{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}

FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.block 'output.state := }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.sentence}
{ output.state after.block =
    'skip$
    { output.state before.all =
        'skip$
        { after.sentence 'output.state := }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
    { #1 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {or}
{   { pop$ #1 }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.block.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}

FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {boldface}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\bf " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\em " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}

INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }

FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, ff}" format.name$ 't :=
      s nameptr "{jj }{ff }{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ 'u :=
      nameptr #1 >
        { namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * u * }
            { t "others" =
                { ", {\em et~al.}" * }
                { " \& " * u * }                           %  Butcher, pages
              if$                                           %  186-189.
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { author format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.key}
{ empty$
    { key field.or.null }
    { "" }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor empty$
    { "" }
    { editor format.names
      editor num.names$ #1 >                                %  Use ODWE abbrevs.
        { " (eds)" * }                                      %  to avoid
        { " (ed)" * }                                       %  ambiguity between
      if$                                                   %  "editor" and
    }                                                       %  "edition".
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.title}                                     %  Nothing needs
{ title empty$                                              %  doing here in
    { "" }                                                  %  authordate1.bst
    { title }                                               %  or
  if$                                                       %  authordate3.bst.
}

FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{ 't :=
  ""
    { t empty$ not }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
        { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
            { "--" *
              t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
            }
            {   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
               { "-" *
                 t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
               }
              while$
            }
          if$
        }
        { t #1 #1 substring$ *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
        if$
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title empty$
   { "" }                                                   %  Don't change case
   { title emphasize }                                      %  in
   if$                                                      %  authordate1.bst
}                                                           %  or
                                                            %  authordate3.bst.
FUNCTION {tie.or.space.connect}
{ duplicate$ text.length$ #3 <
    { "~" }
    { " " }
  if$
  swap$ * *
}

FUNCTION {either.or.check}
{ empty$
    'pop$
    { "can't use both " swap$ * " fields in " * cite$ * warning$ }
  if$
}

INTEGERS { multiresult }

FUNCTION {multi.page.check}
{ 't :=
  #0 'multiresult :=
    { multiresult not
      t empty$ not
      and
    }
    { t #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "-" =
      swap$ duplicate$ "," =
      swap$ "+" =
      or or
        { #1 'multiresult := }
        { t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't := }
      if$
    }
  while$
  multiresult
}

FUNCTION {format.numberinseries}
{ number empty$
    { "" }
    { number multi.page.check
        { ", nos. " number n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }
        { ", no. "  number tie.or.space.connect }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {booklike.series.volume.number}                    %  Chicago, pages
{ series empty$                                             %  450-451.
    { volume empty$
      { " " }
      { " Vol. " volume * }
      if$
    }
    {
      volume empty$
        { number empty$
            { series }
            { series format.numberinseries * }
          if$
        }
        { number empty$
            { series ", vol. " volume * * }
            { series ", vol. " * volume * format.numberinseries * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {incollectionlike.series.volume.number}
{ series empty$
    { volume empty$
      { " " }
      { " vol. " volume * }
      if$
    }
    { new.block
      volume empty$
        { number empty$
            { series }
            { series format.numberinseries * }
          if$
        }
        { number empty$
            { series ", vol. " volume * * }
            { series ", vol. " * volume * format.numberinseries * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.edition}
{ edition empty$
    { "" }
    { output.state mid.sentence =
        { edition "l" change.case$ " edn." * }
        { edition "t" change.case$ " edn." * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages empty$
    { "" }
    { pages multi.page.check
        { "" pages n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }
        { "" pages tie.or.space.connect }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.pagesinbook}                               %  By the time the
{ pages empty$                                              %  reader has read
    { "" }                                                  %  address, pub'r,
    { pages multi.page.check                                %  note (where the
        { "Pages " pages n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }   %  note may end with
        { "Page " pages tie.or.space.connect }              %  numbers), s/he
      if$                                                   %  may not recognise
    }                                                       %  a number-range as
  if$                                                       %  meaning pages.
}                                                           %  Avoid ambiguity
                                                            %  (Butcher, p.181).

FUNCTION {format.vol.num.date.pages}
{ volume empty$
   { month empty$
       { "" }
       { month }
     if$
   }
    { volume boldface field.or.null
        number empty$
        { month empty$
            'skip$
            { "(" month * ")" *  * }
          if$
        }
        { "(" number * ")" *  *
            volume empty$
            { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
            'skip$
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
  pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ format.pages }
        { ", " * pages n.dashify * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages.inbook}
{ chapter empty$
    'format.pagesinbook
    { type empty$
        { "Chap." }
        { type }
      if$
      chapter tie.or.space.connect
      pages empty$
        'skip$
        { ", " * format.pagesinbook "l" change.case$ * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages.incoll}
{ chapter empty$
    { pages empty$
        { "{\em In:} " }
        { "{\em " format.pagesinbook " of:} " * * }
      if$
    }
    { type empty$
        { "{\em Chap. " chapter * }
        { "{\em " type * " " * chapter * }
      if$
      pages empty$
        { " of:} " * }
        { ", " * format.pagesinbook "l" change.case$ " of:} " * * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}                           %  Achieves effect
{ booktitle empty$                                          %  shown in 16.51
    { "" }                                                  %  of Chicago, at
    { editor empty$                                         %  expense of not
        { format.chapter.pages.incoll                       %  achieving effects
          booktitle                  emphasize * }          %  shown in 16.50
        { format.chapter.pages.incoll                       %  of Chicago, on
          format.editors * ", " *                           %  page 189 of
          booktitle                  emphasize * }          %  Butcher and in
      if$                                                   %  4.4 of BS 1629.
    }
  if$                                                       %  Don't change
}                                                           %  case.

FUNCTION {format.thesis.type}
{ type empty$
    'skip$
    { pop$
      type                                                  %  Don't change
    }                                                       %  case.
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.tr.number}
{ type empty$
    { "Tech. rept."  }                                      %  ODWE abbrevs.
    'type
  if$
  number empty$
    {                  }                                    %  Whatever was
    { number tie.or.space.connect }                         %  having its case
  if$                                                       %  changed, leave
}                                                           %  it alone.

FUNCTION {format.addr.pub}
{ publisher empty$
    { "" }
    { address empty$
        { "" }
        { address ": " * }
      if$
      publisher *
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.addr.pub.org}                              %  If there's an
{ address empty$                                            %  an organization
  { publisher * ", for " * organization * }                 %  and a publisher
  { address ": " * publisher * ", for " * organization * }  %  too.
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.addr.inst}
{ address empty$
  { institution empty$
    { "" }
    { institution }
    if$
  }
  { institution empty$
    { "" }
    { institution ", " * }
    if$
    address *
  }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.addr.org}
{ address empty$
  { organization empty$
    { "" }
    { organization }
    if$
  }
  { organization empty$
    { "" }
    { organization ", " * }
    if$
    address *
  }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.article.crossref}
{ "{\em In:}"
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.book.crossref}
{ volume empty$
    { "empty volume in " cite$ * "'s crossref of " * crossref * warning$
      "{\em In:}"
    }
    { " Vol." volume tie.or.space.connect
      " of " *
    }
  if$
  "\cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.incoll.inproc.crossref}
{ "{\em In:}"
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  output.year.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal                  emphasize                    %  Don't change
      "journal" output.check                                %  case.
      format.vol.num.date.pages output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
      editor format.key output
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  output.year.check
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { new.sentence
      format.edition output
      new.block
      booklike.series.volume.number output
      new.block
      format.addr.pub "publisher" output.check
    }
    { new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {booklet}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  output.year.month.check
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.block
  howpublished output
  address output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inbook}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
      editor format.key output
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  output.year.check
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { new.sentence
      format.edition output
      new.block
      booklike.series.volume.number output
      new.block
      format.addr.pub "publisher" output.check
    }
    { new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  new.block                                                 %  BS 1629 (rather
  format.chapter.pages.inbook "chapter and pages" output.check
  fin.entry                                                 %  than Chicago,
}                                                           %  p. 451)

FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "editor" output.check
      editor format.key output             }
    { format.authors "author" output.check
      author format.key output             }
  if$
  output.year.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$                                         %  Chapter and/or
    { format.in.ed.booktitle output                         %  page numbers can
      format.edition output                                 %  come out via this
      incollectionlike.series.volume.number output          %  route, too.
      new.block
      format.addr.pub "publisher" output.check
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      new.block
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  publisher empty$
    { output.year.month.check }
    { output.year.check }
  if$
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      incollectionlike.series.volume.number output
      new.block
      publisher empty$
      {
        organization empty$
        'skip$
        { format.addr.org output }
        if$
      }
      {
        organization empty$
        { format.addr.pub output }
        { format.addr.pub.org output }
        if$
      }
      if$
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {conference} { inproceedings }

FUNCTION {manual}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  output.year.month.check
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.sentence
  format.edition output
  new.block
  organization address new.block.checkb
  format.addr.org output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {mastersthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  output.year.month.check
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.block
  "M.Phil. thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull        %  ODWE abbrev.
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  output.year.month.check
  new.block
  format.btitle output
  new.block
  howpublished output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {phdthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  output.year.month.check
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.block
  "Ph.D. thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull          %  Butcher,
  school "school" output.check                              %  page 174.
  address output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {proceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.editors "author and editor" output.check
  editor format.key output
  publisher empty$
    { output.year.month.check }
    { output.year.check }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.block
  booklike.series.volume.number output
      new.block
      publisher empty$
      {
        organization empty$
        'skip$
        { format.addr.org output }
        if$
      }
      {
        organization empty$
        { format.addr.pub output }
        { format.addr.pub.org output }
        if$
      }
      if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {techreport}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  output.year.month.check
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.block
  format.tr.number output.nonnull
  new.sentence
  format.addr.inst "institution" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {unpublished}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  output.year.month.check
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.block
  note "note" output.check
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }

MACRO {jan} {"Jan."}                                        %  ODWE, "months", &
                                                            %  Chicago, p. 383.
MACRO {feb} {"Feb."}

MACRO {mar} {"Mar."}

MACRO {apr} {"Apr."}

MACRO {may} {"May"}

MACRO {jun} {"June"}

MACRO {jul} {"July"}

MACRO {aug} {"Aug."}

MACRO {sep} {"Sept."}

MACRO {oct} {"Oct."}

MACRO {nov} {"Nov."}

MACRO {dec} {"Dec."}

MACRO {acmcs} {"ACM Computing Surveys"}

MACRO {acta} {"Acta Informatica"}

MACRO {cacm} {"Communications of the ACM"}

MACRO {ibmjrd} {"IBM Journal of Research and Development"}

MACRO {ibmsj} {"IBM Systems Journal"}

MACRO {ieeese} {"IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering"}

MACRO {ieeetc} {"IEEE Transactions on Computers"}

MACRO {ieeetcad}
 {"IEEE Transactions on Computer-Aided Design of Integrated Circuits"}

MACRO {ipl} {"Information Processing Letters"}

MACRO {jacm} {"Journal of the ACM"}

MACRO {jcss} {"Journal of Computer and System Sciences"}

MACRO {scp} {"Science of Computer Programming"}

MACRO {sicomp} {"SIAM Journal on Computing"}

MACRO {tocs} {"ACM Transactions on Computer Systems"}

MACRO {tods} {"ACM Transactions on Database Systems"}

MACRO {tog} {"ACM Transactions on Graphics"}

MACRO {toms} {"ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software"}

MACRO {toois} {"ACM Transactions on Office Information Systems"}

MACRO {toplas} {"ACM Transactions on Programming Languages and Systems"}

MACRO {tcs} {"Theoretical Computer Science"}

READ

FUNCTION {sortify}
{ purify$
  "l" change.case$
}

INTEGERS { len }

FUNCTION {chop.word}
{ 's :=
  'len :=
  s #1 len substring$ =
    { s len #1 + global.max$ substring$ }
    's
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
{ 's :=
  s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  s num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$ " {\em et~al.}" * }
    { #2 <
        'skip$
        { s #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
            { " {\em et~al.}" * }
            { " \& " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.key.label}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
        { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
        'key
      if$
    }
    { author format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.key.label}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
            'key
          if$
        }
        { editor format.lab.names }
      if$
    }
    { author format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.key.label}
{ editor empty$
    { key empty$
        { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
        'key
      if$
    }
    { editor format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {calc.label}
  { type$ "book" =
    type$ "inbook" =
    type$ "incollection" =                                  %  For sensible
  or or                                                     %  treatment of
    'author.editor.key.label                                %  Singer in
    { type$ "proceedings" =                                 %  BS 1629.
        'editor.key.label
        'author.key.label
      if$
    }
  if$
  duplicate$
  year empty$
  {
    "\protect\citename{" swap$ * ", }" *
    "n.d." * 'label :=                                      %  Chicago,
  }                                                         %  page 457.
  {
    "\protect\citename{" swap$ * ", }" *
    year
    *
    'label :=
  }
  if$
  year field.or.null purify$ *
  sortify 'sort.label :=
}


FUNCTION {sort.format.names}                                %  To produce the
{ 's :=                                                     %  order of entries
  #1 'nameptr :=                                            %  specified in item
  ""                                                        %  (3) on page 187
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=                                 %  of Butcher.
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > nameptr #3 < and }                     %  Only 1st 2 names
    { nameptr #1 >                                          %  matter for
        { "   " * }                                         %  sorting.
        'skip$
      if$                                                   %  Anything that's
      nameptr #2 = numnames #2 > and                        %  "et al" goes
      { "zzzzz" * }                                         %  after works by 2
      {                                                     %  authors.
        s nameptr "{vv{ } }{ll{ }}{  ff{ }}{  jj{ }}" format.name$ 't :=
        nameptr numnames = t "others" = and
          { "zzzzz" * }
          { t sortify * }
        if$
      }
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {sort.format.title}
{ 't :=
  "A " #2
    "An " #3
      "The " #4 t chop.word
    chop.word
  chop.word
  sortify
  #1 global.max$ substring$
}

FUNCTION {author.sort}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need author or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.sort}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { "to sort, need author, editor, or key in " cite$ * warning$
              ""
            }
            { key sortify }
          if$
        }
        { editor sort.format.names }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.sort}
{ editor empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need editor or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { editor sort.format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {presort}                                          %  Two sorting
{ calc.label                                                %  passes, from
  label sortify                                             %  apalike.bst.
  "    "
  *
  type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  type$ "incollection" =                                    %  For Singer
  or or                                                     %  in BS 1629.
    'author.editor.sort
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.sort
        'author.sort
      if$
    }
  if$
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.label :=
  sort.label
  *
  "    "
  *
  title field.or.null
  sort.format.title
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}

ITERATE {presort}

SORT

STRINGS { last.label next.extra }

INTEGERS { last.extra.num }

FUNCTION {initialize.extra.label.stuff}
{ #0 int.to.chr$ 'last.label :=
  "" 'next.extra :=
  #0 'last.extra.num :=
}

FUNCTION {forward.pass}
{ last.label label =
    { last.extra.num #1 + 'last.extra.num :=
      last.extra.num int.to.chr$ 'extra.label :=
    }
    { "a" chr.to.int$ 'last.extra.num :=
      "" 'extra.label :=
      label 'last.label :=
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {reverse.pass}
{ next.extra "b" =
    { "a" 'extra.label := }
    'skip$
  if$                                                       %  Code needed here
                                                            %  if \citeauthor
                                                            %  and \citeyear
  label extra.label * 'label :=                             %  were supported.
  extra.label 'next.extra :=
}

EXECUTE {initialize.extra.label.stuff}

ITERATE {forward.pass}

REVERSE {reverse.pass}

FUNCTION {bib.sort.order}
{ sort.label
  "    "
  *
  year field.or.null sortify
  *
  "    "
  *
  title field.or.null
  sort.format.title
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}

ITERATE {bib.sort.order}

SORT

FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{}" write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {begin.bib}

EXECUTE {init.state.consts}

ITERATE {call.type$}

FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
  "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {end.bib}
```

For the record, the modifications as listed by the Unix/Linux command

```
diff my_authordate1.bst `kpsewhich authordate1.bst`
```

```
37c107
< STRINGS { s t u }
---
> STRINGS { s t }
194d263
<       s nameptr "{jj }{ff }{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ 'u :=
197c266
<             { ", " * u * }
---
>             { ", " * t * }
200c269
<                 { " \& " * u * }                           %  Butcher, pages
---
>                 { ", \& " * t * }                           %  Butcher, pages
```

Comment: It works perfectly, ton of thanks